# Conditional followed by imperative

Tags: syntax, terminology, imperative, conditionals

In English, we have often sentences like so:

> If you are interested, send me a message

> WHEN you are ready to do it, start with the laundry

To my understanding these are a conditional followed by an imperative. Is there a name for this type of sentence in general languages?

Comment: I'd call it a conditional imperative. Do this, under these conditions. Though there are hundreds of ways to express it, and the order of the conditional part and the impositive part is not fixed.

Comment: There's also the meta-conditional statements: _If you haven't been listening, Brazil is ahead by one goal_.  The _if_ clause does not affect the truth of the conclusion, which is asserted.